# How to compute the minimum possible sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, summation

Given two sets of having equal number of unique numbers we need to find the minimum possible sum.
Where sum is the square of the difference of the number taken one at a time as a pair and each number can be used only once.
Example: if we have A[3,5,8] and B[4,6,10]
here one possible sum could be,

$$(3-4)^2 +(5-6)^2+(8-10)^2=6$$

Comment: A pair of numbers can be used only once, or each number itself can be used only once?

Comment: sorry, each number.

Comment: @AndreyKaipov ?

Comment: What's stopping us from taking A[6,4,2] and B[5,3,1] yielding a sum of 3? Each square of the difference between two respective numbers can't be 0 since the numbers are unique, and presumably we're only working with integers, so we can't have anything lower than a sum of 3.

Comment: We are given two sets of numbers, we have to find the respective minimum sum.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I'm not well today...

Comment: Its OK keep care :) if you could think anything let us know :D.

Comment: I think you just need to sort each list from least to greatest and take the difference that should give you the min value

Answer (score 1):

You should sort both lists in increasing order so that $A=[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ and $B=[y_1,y_2,...,y_n]$ are sorted with $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$ and $y_1<y_2<...<y_n$. Then the minimal squared sum is
$$
S_{\min}=(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2
$$

---

To see this, consider the somewhat simpler case of $n=2$ with $A=[x,x+s]$ and $B=[y,y+t]$ for some positive integers $s,t$. Here we only have two candidates for the sums, namely
$$
S_1=(x-y)^2+((x+s)-(y+t))^2=2(x-y)^2+2(x-y)(s-t)+(s-t)^2
$$
and
$$
S_2=(x-(y+t))^2+((x+s)-y)^2=2(x-y)^2+2(x-y)(s-t)+s^2+t^2
$$
And we see that $S_2-S_1=2st>0$ so $S_1$ following the ordering of $A$ and $B$ is minimal for the case $n=2$.

---

Now let us turn to the general case for an arbitrary number of elements $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose $A$ has been sorted so that $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$ whereas $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ are not sorted. Then we may identify an inversion ie. $y_i>y_{i+1}$, but then the $n=2$ case tells us that switching $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ improves the squared sum. Continuing like this, eventually $B$ has been sorted, improving the squared sum for each time we eliminate an inversion.